# TypeInitializationException with Moq and Moles when using [HostType("Moles")]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, moles

Moq throws a TypeInitializationException when using Moles with the `[HostType("Moles")]` attribute. Code example and exception below.

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IAnything>();
}
```

The exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
  Message=The type initializer for 'Moq.Extensions' threw an exception.
  Source=Moq
  TypeName=Moq.Extensions
  StackTrace:
       at Moq.Extensions.IsMockeable(Type typeToMock)
       at Moq.Mock`1.CheckParameters()
       at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior, Object[] args)
       at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior)
       at Moq.Mock`1..ctor()
       at BP.DFR.Common.Services.Network.DfrNetworkQueryTests.MyTestMethod()
  InnerException: System.Security.VerificationException
       Message=Operation could destabilize the runtime.
       Source=Moq
       StackTrace:
            at Moq.Extensions..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

The link below suggested it might be a moq version issue, but it happens in both version 3.1 and 4.0 for me.

http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=344

I'm using VS 2010 Premium SP1. Anybody had any luck resolving this?

Comment: What happen if you remove [HostType("Moles")]?